# How to update my weight in the Activity app

Tags: iphone, apple-watch

I want to change the weight that I originally used to set up the Activity app, but I cannot see a way of editing the setup.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Activity app uses the info stored in the Health app.

To change your weight:

1. Open the `Watch` app on the iPhone
2. On the `My Watch` tab, scroll down and tap on `Health`
3. Tap `Edit` in the top right corner
4. Scroll through the weights and select the correct one

You can also do this on the iPhone in the Health app under `Body Measurements`.

Once that is done, Activity will use the updated value.

Answer (score 4):

*In addition to fsb's correct answer*, I've used [Workflow](https://www.workflow.is) to create a widget that allows me to update my weight more quickly than drilling down into the health app (since that app always launches in the last position I left it and I use it for other things, I always found it to be 3 or 4 taps before being able to enter my weight.)

There are other apps I've used in the past:

[Lose It!](https://www.loseit.com)

and

[Scelta](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/weight-tracker-scelta/id1271098229?mt=8)

both give easier access to adjusting your weight if you want to keep it current.

Comment: Beat me to it! Workflow widget helps me log my weight more regularly.

Comment: I also use Workflow lock screen widget to do this (and a few other things, also).